# Fresh App Store Submission vs. App Update

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I am interested in the time a completlye new App Store Submission takes compared to an update submitted to an already existing app in the App Store.

Any experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every update I made to an application has taken the same amount of time as submitting a new.

Comment: Anyone with different experiences?

Comment: No. It is always the same :(

Comment: I didn't experience any difference. I have submitted a new app as well as an updated app and the approval came with a difference of only 1 day.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes iOS App store approval of updates is faster.  Sometimes it's slower than a new app.  The variance in both approval times can be quite large, depending on app features, annual product cycles, phase of the moon, and etc.